# How to get contacts in Android

Tags: android

I am a developing an application for composing sms in android platform. For that i need to get "Contacts", "Recent Contacts" and "Groups". Please tell me any tutorial or the code of how to do it. When we click on any of these three buttons there should be contacts along with a checkbox for selecting multiple contacts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

here is the code to get contacts programmatically

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    null, null, null);
  String id = null, name = null, email = null, phone = null, note = null, orgName =     null, title = null;
  String Phone1 = "unknown", Phone2 = "unknown", Phone3 = "unknown", type1 = "unknown",        type2 = "unknown", type3 = "unknown";
  int size = cur.getCount();
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    int cnt = 1;
    while (cur.moveToNext())
    {
        email = "";
        name = "";
        cnt++;
        id = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        name = cur
                .getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if (name != null && name != "") {
            if (!checkEmail(name)) {
                email = "";

            } else {
                email = name;
                name = "";
            }
        }
        if (Integer
                .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)

        {
            System.out.println("name : " + name);
            Cursor pCur = cr
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                            null);

            Phone1 = " ";
            Phone2 = " ";
            Phone3 = " ";
            while (pCur.moveToNext())
            {
                String phonetype = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                String MainNumber = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                if (phonetype.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Phone1 = MainNumber;
                    type1 = "home";
                } else if (phonetype.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                    Phone2 = MainNumber;
                    type2 = "mobile";
                } else {
                    Phone3 = MainNumber;
                    type3 = "work";
                }
            }
            pCur.close();

        }
            Cursor addrCur = cr
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                            null);
            if (addrCur.getCount() == 0) {
                addbuffer.append("unknown");
            } else {
                int cntr = 0;
                while (addrCur.moveToNext()) {

                    cntr++;
                    String poBox = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                    if (poBox == null) {
                        poBox = " ";
                    }
                    String street = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                    if (street == null) {
                        street = " ";
                    }
                    String neb = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD));
                    if (neb == null) {
                        neb = " ";
                    }
                    String city = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                    if (city == null) {
                        city = " ";
                    }
                    String state = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                    if (state == null) {
                        state = " ";
                    }
                    String postalCode = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                    if (postalCode == null) {
                        postalCode = " ";
                    }
                    String country = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                    if (country == null) {
                        country = " ";
                    }

                    String type = addrCur
                            .getString(addrCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
                    if (type == null) {
                        type = " ";
                    }
                }

            }

            addrCur.close();

            String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                    + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                    + " = ?";
            String[] noteWhereParams = new String[] {
                    id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
            Cursor noteCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);

            note = " ";

            if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                note = noteCur
                        .getString(noteCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));

                if (note == null) {
                    note = " ";
                }
            }
            noteCur.close();
            String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                    + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                    + " = ?";
            String[] orgWhereParams = new String[] {
                    id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
            Cursor orgCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
            orgName = " ";
            if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                orgName = orgCur
                        .getString(orgCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY));

            }
            if (orgName == null) {
                orgName = " ";
            }
            orgCur.close();

            Cursor emailCur = cr
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                            null);
            email = "unknown";
            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {

                email = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                String emailType = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                if (email == null) {
                    email = "unknown";
                }
                if (emailType.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                } else {
                }
            }

            // add
            emailCur.close();
```

Comment: this is the running code in my application. ask me if you have any furthe query

Comment: what does the checkEmail and addBuffer functions do?

Comment: @rosualin CheckEmail method is to check for valid email address(email syntax )

Comment: 10x, and the other is a TextView, manage to make it work, and took out the code i didn't need, I only needed the emails, so this way it is faster, without checking the DB for phones, addresses and etc.